# Theme gif not cached

Tags: wss-3.0, caching

We have a site running on wss 3.0, in a cluster with a hardware load balancer. The site is NOT https. All clients are running IE6.

About 60% of the traffic is for a single gif /sites/xxxx/_themes/Lacquer/viewheadergrad_lacquer.gif

Anyone know what could cause this gif not to be cached in the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you used [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/), [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/) or [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843/) to analyze the request made by the browser and the response sent by the server?

This will indicate whether the problem is client side or server side.

Comment: Thanks, it turned out thatcaching was turned off in the browser